# Reading both numbers in an integer instead of the first when sorting

Tags: python, sorting, integer

I'm trying to sort data from a text file and show it in python.

So far i have:

```
                text_file = open ("Class1.txt", "r")
                data = text_file.read().splitlines()

                namelist, scorelist = [],[]
                for li in data:
                    namelist.append(li.split(":")[0])
                    scorelist.append(li.split(":")[1])
                scorelist.sort()
                print (scorelist)
                text_file.close()
```

It sorts the the data, however it only reads the first number:

```
['0', '0', '10', '3', '3', '5']
```

It reads 10 as "1"

This is what my text file looks like:

```
Harry:3
Jarrod:10
Jacob:0
Harold:5
Charlie:3
Jj:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `scorelist` is a list of *strings*, `"10"` shows up before `"3"` because the first character in `"10"` is less than the first character in `"3"` (lexicographic sorting -- like words in a dictionary).  The trick here is to tell python to sort integers.  You can do that as the other answers point out by sorting a list of integers rather than a list of strings, *OR* you could use a `key` function to sort:

```
scorelist.sort(key=int)
```

This tells python to sort the items as integers rather than as strings.  The nice thing here is that you don't need to change the data at all.  You still end up with a list of strings rather than a list of integers -- you just tell python to change how it *compares* the strings.  Neat.

---

demo:

```
>>> scorelist = ['3', '10', '0', '5', '3', '0']
>>> scorelist_int = [int(s) for s in scorelist]
>>>
>>> scorelist.sort(key=int)
>>> scorelist
['0', '0', '3', '3', '5', '10']
>>>
>>> scorelist_int.sort()
>>> scorelist_int
[0, 0, 3, 3, 5, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's lexographically sorting, if you need integer sorting, append the split as an `int`

```
scorelist.append(int(li.split(":")[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The data are actually strings. The sort is done like in a dictionary.

You should convert scores into int:

```
scorelist.append(int(li.split(":")[1]))
```